# My Minecraft Servers won't show up- Not Multiplayer or Singleplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I play my mine craft on a Macbook Pro, Recently I had gotten it to work again, And saw my old servers. I played on a couple of them for awhile, But none had nothing much on them. I had a giant list of Multiplayer servers as that is all I played on. Recently, I signed on and realized that none of my Servers were there. I thought that maybe it was from me changing my username from chloe4068 to ScarletWolfGames, But even with the name change my servers were still there. I went to download an adventure map and Put it in the saves folder, In which, My old servers were still on. Well. My single player ones anyway. I thought my old servers would be back, I played again, They weren't there. Before I had played I had deleted copies of mine craft folders with the same things in them, well, same folders. I had then lost my servers, But seeing how they still exist but aren't in the game confuses me. Any help?

Comment: Single player servers? Are you talking about your savegames rather than servers perhaps?

Comment: Oh! Oh yeah! Forgot to add that onto there. Yes the folder I found was my saved games, I found my old servers while trying to download the Adventure Map, Which I had stated in the explanation.

Comment: what are servers and what is save-games? I need more info to answer this. I may know an answer, but I need you to edit it to where we can tell the difference in servers and single-player games.

Answer (score 1):

The (multiplayer) servers are stored in the `servers.bat` file, which you might have deleted. Singleplayer worlds on the other hand are stored in the `saves` folder, which is in your case still there.

Comment: Isn't it `servers.dat`?